# How can my Perl script detect when a child process (run with `system`) is killed?

Tags: perl, signals, child-process, sigint

My Perl script

```
while (blah)
{
    system ("wget $blah");
}
```

does not die when I ctrl-c. Instead the child process `wget` dies, and the while-loop continues.

How can the parent Perl process detect this and terminate?

Comment: The title and the text body aren't the same.  If your objective is to have the program exit on Ctrl-C then trap the signal and do what you need in the handler.  But if you  need to know when and how a child process got terminated then that's a much more rounded question.

Answer (score 3):

Check the return value of [system](http://p3rl.org/system):

```
0 == system "wget $blah" or die "Can't get $blah.";
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer qx (backtracks than system). Here is an example using backtracks. However, you can do the same with system.

```
use English;    ## So i can use $OS_ERROR rather than $!. see perlvar for more info
qx(exit 1);     ## anything other than 0 is an error in Linux
print "failed\n" if $OS_ERROR;    ## you can die here
```

However, wget may not always fail. you may get served a 404 page, which will not be picked up as a failure.

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;    ## use Mojo
my $url = "http://madeup.com/hdhd";   
my $res = Mojo::UserAgent->new->get($url)->result; 
unless ($res->code==200) {
print "ERROR\n".$res->message."\n"; ## you can use die here
}
```

Same As above using HTTP::Tiny

```
use HTTP::Tiny;    ## use http tiny
my $url = "https://makeup.com/hdhd"; 
my $res = HTTP::Tiny->new->get($url); 
unless ($res->{success}) {
  print "ERROR\n".$res->{status}."\n";  ## you can die here
}
```

Comment: You have to be careful. Non-zero exit does not always mean it's an error. You should compare it to the expected exit code (which is usually zero).  Also note that HTTP has several codes that are "Successful". You can use `is_success` instead of testing for a particular HTTP code (unless that's the only one you'll accept). Consider the 300 series, for example.

Comment: HTTP::Tiny comes with Perl, so everyone should already have it.

Comment: With Mojo::UserAgent you should use the $res->is_success and $res->is_error methods.

Comment: $res->is_success returns true for status codes such as 301. It's hard to know if this should be a pass on the information available in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to do my own `fork` and manage the process more closely if I want to actually think about the child. Set up various signal handlers, exit with appopriate values, and so on. That gives you fine-grained control over what's happening. That forked process might even `exec` to become `wget`. And, since it's a different process, you can send signals to it directly.

But, if wget is the command you want to use, I'd wonder why you weren't using a module to do that work. You'd get a lot more control when you have access to the request and response info.